# Populate a dataframe with two actionButtons

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a bit stuck on this shiny problem. I have two actionButtons representing group membership (group 1 vs. group 2). I'd like if a user clicks one button to populate a two column data-frame with the group selected and the date/time it was submitted and for it to show on the page. I can get the group + date/time to print to console on click but I could use some help getting to populate a table.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Select your group"),
   br(),
  column(
    6,
   actionButton("group1", "Group 1", style = 'padding:4px; font-size:50px'),
   ),
   column(
     6,
     actionButton("group2", "Group 2", style = 'padding:4px; font-size:50px'),
   )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

click <- date()

observeEvent(input$group1,  {print(paste0("Group1: ", click))})
observeEvent(input$group2,{print(paste0("Group2: ", click))})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea. Everytime you click on a button the table gets a new row with information. For a better impression the hole table is shown on the user interface.

```
library(shiny)



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Select your group"),
  br(),
  column(
    6,
    actionButton("group1", "Group 1", style = 'padding:4px; font-size:50px'),
  ),
  column(
    6,
    actionButton("group2", "Group 2", style = 'padding:4px; font-size:50px'),
  ),
  br(),
  tableOutput('table')
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame(group = NA, time = NA)
  
  observeEvent(input$group1,  {
    newLine <- c("group1", date())
    isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df, newLine))
    })
  observeEvent(input$group2,  {
    newLine <- c("group2", date())
    isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df, newLine))
    })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(values$df) 
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! reactiveValues() and isolate() is what I need to dig deeper into. Thanks again :)

Comment: I think `isolate` is not necessary in this case, or am I overlooking something?